# Lost connection with database using node-postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I having a problem with `node-postgres`, sometimes I lost connection from `PG`. To get it back, I always needs to restart server.

here is the code snippet:

```js
const pg = require('pg');

let connectionString;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  connectionString = 'postgres://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DB';
} else {
  connectionString = 'postgres://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DB';
}

const pool = new pg.Pool({
  connectionString: connectionString,
})
```

Someone could help me, please? I dont know why..

Comment: I would start with looking into your postgres-logs -> [Error Logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/runtime-config-logging.html). If you running postgresql under linux, check out `/var/logs/postgresql`

Comment: `I always needs to restart the server` - are you talking about your node backend or the complete server where postgresql is running on?